# Torque issues with DC motor

Tags: dc-motor, torque, rpm

I am currently trying to use a DC motor with a lead screw to eventually open an close a window. My window requires around 2 kg's of force to open and the distance that needs to be traveled is 20 inches.

As I lack knowledge in this field, I ordered the wrong motor for my job ([Motor](https://hallroad.org/nisca-dc-24v-1.3a-5600-rpm-na4565d-in-pakistan.html)). It has too high of an RPM(5500) and not enough torque to even move .6 kgs. Here is the datasheet(My version is NA4565D, [datasheet](https://ftn.canon/en/product/motor/list.html)). When powering with my power supply, it only draws about .12 Amps(at 24v). How can I reduce the RPM and increase the torque? If possible without the use of gears, as i don't own a 3D printer to make them. And if there is no reliable way to do this, How can one do it **with** gears? And how would one calculate the required torque?
Thanks in advance, do let me know if I can give you any more helpful info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use belts and pulleys, or buy gears and try to assemble a reducer, but I think you'd be better off just buying a gear-head motor. There is no way to electronically increase the torque much beyond the rated torque- we can reduce the speed and it's possible with some effort to **maintain** the torque. A gear-head motor will have the reduction gear train integrated into the motor assembly.

You need linear motion rather than rotary, which points to the use of a leadscrew (as you mention) or timing belt kind of arrangement. Calculating the torque required is more mechanical engineering but I think you can estimate it from lever arms and so on, and add a healthy safety factor to account for friction in the slides and drive train.

You probably also should consider a safety stop so that the window does not double as a dull guillotine as well as end-of-travel limit stops, of course.